# Many to Many DataMapper CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm stuck and reading the documentation doesn't seem to be helping me out.

I have one to many relationships working, all though I'm sure there is an easier way, I'm stuck when it comes to Many to Many relationships.

I've tried quite a few things, but basically I have three tables:

```
homes:
- id
- address_id
- price
- etc

features:
- id
- name

features_homes
- id
- feature_id
- home_id
```

I've setup my model quite a few different ways.

```
var $has_many = array(
    'feature' => array(
        'class' => 'feature',
        'other_field' => 'home',
        'join_self_as' => 'home',
        'join_other_as' => 'feature',
        'join_table' => 'features_homes'
    )
);
```

And the basic version of

```
var $has_many = array('feature');
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to get multiple records associated with the home.

I end up with a single item rather than a group of items.

**Example output:**

```
[id] => 1
[address_id] => 1
[latlong] => 00.000, -00.00000
...
[feature_id] => 1
[feature_name] => Hard Wood Floors
```

I am trying to get

```
[id] => 1
[address_id] => 1
[latlong] => 00.000, -00.00000
...
[features] => // Object of all items
```

Answer (score 1):

You associate one object to another by linking them when you save.

You can do that multiple times:

```
$parent = new Parent(1);
$childA = new Child(1);
$childB = new Child(2);

$parent->save($childA); $parent->save($childB);
```

Or by passing an array:

```
$parent = new Parent(1);
$children = array(
    new Child(1),
    new Child(2),
);

$parent->save($children);
```

Comment: What if you already have this data saved in a database that you are trying to access? Do you have to save everything with DataMapper before you can display it the way you want?

Comment: Then you'll fetch them instead of creating them.

Comment: The framework is really cool, but I think I need to keep beating it up to really figure it out. I have something that just isn't right, and I'm sure it's my code. Do you know of any good tutorials online that walk your through different scenarios? I was able to get the results I was looking for, but I had to do a loop inside a loop to get the data. I think my models need to be changed somehow so I can group multiple results under a single key in the object.

Comment: Quick question...so I just discovered this, `$obj->subobj->all` is this the best way to get all the related objects?

Comment: Yes. All Datamapper objects implement ArrayIterator, so you can simply foreach over $obj->subobj without having to be bothered with the all array.

Comment: Can you take a peek at this question when you have time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593008/datamapper-all-to-json-method-returning-slashes